# unable to add user in google group, getting an error- "code": 403, "message": "Insufficient Permission"

Tags: php, token, google-groups, google-groups-api

I am unable to add a user to google groups. I am able to generate Token and using this for my calendar API-

1. Is an Access Token generating for G Calendar API can be used for the process of adding a user to a Google Group PLS?
2. If No for above asked Step then how to generate a token for Google Groups?
3. Reason for throwing an error with 403 error code, Error is given below

   ```
   "{ "error": 
       { "errors": 
           [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "insufficientPermissions", "message": "Insufficient Permission" } ], 
          "code": 403, "message": "Insufficient Permission" 
       } 
   }"
   ```
4. I am using an account `svc.gcalendar@timesinternet.in` for doing above and I want to add a user name `devendra.kumarsingh@timesinternet.in`
5. The reproduction was successful in API Explorer while unable to generate a token using my api.
6. My code is

   ```
   $groupKey='TIL-Gurgaon@timesinternet.in'; //TIL-Noida@timesinternet.in
   $role='MEMBER';
   $userEmail='devendra.kumarsingh@timesinternet.in';
   $curlPost=array();
   $curlPost = array("email"=>$userEmail,"role"=>$role);       
   $url_events = 'https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/'.$groupKey.'/members';     
   $condtion['user_email']='svc.gcalendar@timesinternet.in';
   //Getting Token 
   $datalist=$this->Common->getSingleInfoFromTable('oauth_session',$condtion,'id');
   $access_token=$datalist['access_token'];

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_events);
   //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
   //xcurl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '. $access_token, 'Content-Type: application/json'));
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($curlPost));
   $data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
   $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
   ```

Comment: Please limit your post to just one question.

Comment: I have to add a user to google groups using google api

Answer (score 0):

This "add by api" feature is only available for those organizations with a gsuite subscription. Can you confirm you have GSuite and are logged in under the account that is both GSuite enabled and also authorized to do the adding to the group?

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-group-members